# Reduce lifecycle validation calls in resizeable Flex LabelItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, itemrenderer

I've subclassed the `LabelItemRenderer` class to create an expandable renderer for a spark list in my mobile app.

When the user selects an item, the renderer's size increases, additional data is shown. The renderer basically looks like this (I've removed the parts that don't matter here, so this is basically pseudo code).

```
public class PositionsGridRenderer extends LabelItemRenderer
{
    public function PositionsGridRenderer() {
        super();
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, expandHandler);
    }

    protected override function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren();

        _dg = new DataGroup();
        _dg.visible = false;
        addChild(_dg);
    }

    private function expandHandler(event:Event):void {
        if(_gridVisible) {
            if(!_detailClicked) {
                _dg.visible = false;
                _gridVisible = false;
            }
            _detailClicked = false;
        } else {
            _dg.visible = true;
            _gridVisible = true;
        }
    }

    public override function set data(value:Object):void {
        if(!value) return;

        super.data = value;

        var pos:Position = data as Position;

        label = pos.positionName;
        _dg.dataProvider = pos.positionSymbols;
    }

    protected override function measure():void {
        !_gridVisible ? measuredHeight = 30 : measuredHeight = 30 + getElementPreferredHeight(_dg);
        this.height = measuredHeight;
    }

    protected override function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        setElementSize(labelDisplay, unscaledWidth, 30);
        setElementPosition(labelDisplay, 10,10);
        if(_gridVisible) {
            setElementSize(_dg, unscaledWidth, getElementPreferredHeight(_dg));
            setElementPosition(_dg, 0, 30);

        } else {
            setElementSize(_dg, unscaledWidth, 0);
        }

        invalidateSize();
    }
}
```

}

Works as expected, I'm just wondering if there's a way to reduce the amount of validation calls this renderer does when I expand it.
If it is clicked to be expanded the `layoutContents` and `measure` functions are both called three times in the following order: layoutcontents -> measure, layoutcontens -> measure, layoutcontents -> measure.

I'd understand them being called once because I invalidate the size, but three times seems odd.
Does anyone know why this is happening, or maybe even how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I'm unclear how the renderer is resized from your post.  Is it like a window, where the user clicks and drags to set some new size?  Or is it some fixed option that switches between two separate sizes on the click of a button?

Comment: It is fixed. See the renderer has an initial size of 30. Take a look at the `measure()` function. When the grid (the optional data to be shown) is not visible, the renderer's size remains at 30. When the grid is shown (toggled by the `expandHandler()` function), the renderer's size increases to the initial size (30) plus the preferred height of the grid.

Comment: I know you said this was psuedo-code; but shouldn't the 'override' be before the protected, not after?  Is 'super' being called for layoutContents and/or measure?  If you invalidateSize() in layoutContents, wouldn't that trigger a new validation cycle every time the component is redrawn?  A lot of interactions can invalidateDisplayList(); but I don't see it you doing it manually so I'm not clear what is causing it.

Comment: Actually, the `override` can stand either before or after the access modifiers. I usually write them before as well, but the code is from a colleague who does it like this. Makes no difference though. No, super is not called for either `measure` or `layoutContents`. The code basically resembles the exact renderer, what I left out are just parts that don't matter for this "issue" such as drawing the background or other parts of the renderer aside the detail grid (i.e. another detail group below the grid). Yes, the `invalidateSize` does trigger another cycle, which is fine and actually required

Comment: for the renderer to increase it's size. Well, I just found out that select on a list item does trigger another cycle, which would account for two cycles in total. Now I just have to find out what causes the third one. Cause if three is normal, than that's ok, I just don't want to waste performance by lousy code that triggers unnecessary validation cycles.

Comment: Could your third renderer cycle be a TouchBegin (or mouseOver?) event?  I think that touchBegin causes a hover style to display, which invalidatesDisplayList().  Then the selection will cause a 'selected' style to display; which also calls invalidatesDisplayList.

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't think about the `down` state at all. So all cycles are now accounted for. Guess there's nothing left to discuss then as we won't be able to alter that behavior. Thanks a lot! Please sum up your comment in a short answer so that I can accept it for future readers.

Comment: One thing that Flextras mentioned was calling invalidateSize() at the end of layoutContents(). That seems unnecessary. It should have already happened when you get to layoutContents(). Ideally, you should invalidate the properties and then in commit properties(), invalidate size and display list. Here you seem to invalidate size every time the display list is updated.

Comment: @SunilD., I tried it the way to said, invalidating the properties in my expand handler and calling `invalidateSize()` in the `commitProperties()` (invalidating the displayList isn't required actually), the renderer's behaviour is indeed the same, but `measure` is still called twice, `layoutContents` three times. Was this the correct way you had in mind? I mean calling `commitProperties()` (including the `commitProperties` ofc) is probably slower than having an additional `measure` call instead, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question was why is the component going through three full renderer cycles? After some disussion, this is what we came across:

1. The first time the invalidate cycle is triggered is when a mouse down, or possibly a touch begin event occurs.  This puts the component into the hover state; which causes a visual change in the component.
2. The second time the invalidate cycle is triggered is when the item is selected.  This puts the renderer in the down state; causing a different visual indicator to be drawn.
3. The third invalidate cycle is caused by the component's own code; when layoutContents() calls invalidatesize()